# Why do I have to rebuild/restart my asp.net web application in visual studio on one project and not on the other one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, rebuild

I have two different asp.net web- applications. One was created with vs2010, the other one was created with vs2012. I do now only use vs2012 for both of them.

There is one thing I do not understand:

In my older application created with vs2010 I can change the code in my .cs file and all I have to do is to press F5 in my Browser to see the changes.

On the newer application I always have to rebuild or restart to see the changes I made. Why is that? Is it possible to change that?

Both projects are asp.net/c# with .net framework 4.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the title you mention having to restart VS itself while in your description it sounds like you just need to restart the debugging process. You may want to update the title to clarify exactly what you mean.

Comment: Thank you, I have modified the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that one of your projects was set up as a "Web Application" project and the other as a "Web Site" project. The difference between the two are described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx

It's important to note that although you may find them more convenient, "Web Site" projects have been essentially deprecated after VS2012 and have not received access to many new ASP.NET features.

As far as editing code without restarting in a "Web Application" I'd recommend looking into the Edit & Continue functionality, which allows you to edit code while debugging. Although it definitely has its limitations. You can read more about that here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x17d7wxw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you very much, thats the reason :-)